# Interernet is not available in Browser

Tags: linux-mint, internet, browser, connectivity

I am using Linux Mint 19.1. I am getting internet in Laptop but I am not getting internet in Browser.

My laptop suddenly shut down after that I am not getting internet in my Browser.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you are pinging an IP address, but you are trying to connect to a website by name .... ping facebook 157.240.3.35 ... also try putting that IP in the browser

Comment: In light of what is stated in the [Meta post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/315749) about avoiding posting images of text, I'd suggest you to add some description of what your images are showing. (Personally, I'd say you may just replace them with some text as "successfully ping 8.8.8.8", "Firefox says "we can't connect to the server at wwww.facebook.com"", ...)

Comment: please start `firefox -P` create a new profile, and start with them. Same error?